# How to install mysql cluster?

Tags: mysql

How to install Mysql Cluster 7.1 or 7.2 on Ubuntu 10.11 ?
On a fresh install of Ubuntu, we must uninstall pre-installed mysql before?
What is the best way, use .tar.gz on Mysql Website with or witout glibc or user apt-get install mysql-cluster-client-5.1 and mysql-cluster-server-5.1 ? I think that have a bug with these packages.. Please help. thx.

Comment: There is no such thing as 10.11 .. did you mean 11.10?

Answer (score 2):

You can leave the regular MySQL installation in place if you like and then follow the instructions in the [MySQL Cluster quick-start guide](http://downloads.mysql.com/tutorials/cluster/GetMySQLClusterRunningLinux.pdf) to install, configure and run MySQL Cluster from the tar ball.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do to install a mySQL Cluster:

1. Go ahead and grab the latest package software from the [source](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/cluster).
2. You will need to locate the package that you just downloaded (usually in the downloads file) and extract the files to a directory of your choosing.
3. In `terminal` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) create a link to the extracted files (this will vary depending on where you extracted too. Should go something along the lines of `tar xvf File Path/Filename.tar.gz && ln -s mysql-cluster-gpl-7.1.2-linux-x86_64-glibc23 mysqlc` after the `&&` you will need to know what package you downloaded to input the correct information.
4. You will need to initiate your mySQL management node, data nodes, and eventually your mySQL Server.

Its always best practice to place your cluster in the **root** of your directory to keep things simple, but its really up to you. Good luck!